# Convert elastic search query + aggregations to nest syntax

Tags: elasticsearch, c#-4.0, nest

I need to turn the following nested query and aggregations as written in Kibana to c# nest syntax.
The main issue is regarding the "harvest-date" sub-aggregation (I need to set it to the last 3 months). but also not sure the query itself is the best practice.

```
GET tdnetindex/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "TermsAggregation": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "database",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "DateHistogramAggregation": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "harvest_date",
            "interval": "month"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "harvest_date": {
            "gte": "now-3M/M"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

what I did so far was:

```
var query = elasticClient.Search<ElasticResponse>(s => s
                .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(a1 => a1
                    .Terms("TermsAggregation", t => t
                        .Field(f => f.DataBase)
                        .Size(100)
                        .Aggregations(a2 => a2
                            .DateHistogram("DateHistogramAggregation", dh => dh
                            .Field(f => f.HarvestDate)
                            .Interval(DateInterval.Month)
                            )
                        )
                    )
            )
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Filter(f => f
                        .Range(r => r
                            .GreaterThanOrEquals(....);
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
           )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're *almost* there, just need to use `.DateRange(r => r...)` instead of `.Range(r => r...)`.

For the DateMath expression, you can use the string `"now-3M/M"` directly, or translate to

```
DateMath.Now.Subtract("3M").RoundTo(DateMathTimeUnit.Month)
```